# Why is my Flask app processing requests for a different, and unfamilar, domain (http://imagefreak007.com/2ch.php)?

Tags: http-status-code-404, flask

I have a Flask app running on a domain - let's say abc.com. It logs all 404 errors so I can review them and in the log it includes the request.url value. This works well but occasionally I get a log entry with a request.url value of "http://imagefreak007.com/2ch.php". It's always the same url - same domain and page.

I thought the request object, and specifically the url value, indicated the url the client is trying to access - which I assumed must be on the same domain/s that the Flask app is running on. I am not sure where the url value is coming from - it is not an intentional part of the Flask app.

Comment: Is imagefreak007.com your domain? http://www.intodns.com/imagefreak007.com

Comment: Nope. I had not heard of the domain until it appeared in my 404 error log. Since posting the question, I have received 404 errors for different urls on different domains. When I looked up those urls it pointed to discussion forums indicating they are bots scanning for vulnerabilities and are considered normal Internet traffic. I am still unclear why they are the appearing as a flask request url though.

Answer (score 1):

**A client can always lie about the hostname it is trying to access.** If your site is `example.com`, the following would be a normal HTTP request:

```
GET /some/path
Host: example.com
```

The requests you recieve are also sent to `example.com`, but are probably something like:

```
GET /2ch.php
Host: imagefreak007.com
```

You can try this out with the `telnet` command: execute `telnet example.com 80`, then type one of the requests in the prompt and hit enter twice at the end.